# How to build a heater circuit with a Raspbery Pico?

Tags: mosfet, heater

I am building a Raspberry Pico controlled heater.

The heater is just a nichrome wire with 4 Ω resistance and the power source is three 18650 Samsung batteries connected in series (~4 V, 20 A each). I want the heat output to be controlled by a Raspberry Pico with a k-type thermocouple.

I researched and discovered that a transistor is needed to be used as a switch and it should be able to handle the source voltage and current (also power). So I decided to use an [IRLB3034PBF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlb3034pbf.pdf) MOSFET and connect its gate to the Pico's 3.3 V pin (schematic below).

My problem is that I have not tried it out yet, because I don't want to fry my Raspberry Pico or make a battery explode; first I want to ask some questions:

1. Should I use a MOSFET or did I do something wrong and should I choose something like a 2N2222?
2. Should I use a resistor between the 3.3 V pin and the MOSFET's gate (the IRLN3034PBG is opened by 1 to 2.5 V if I am correct)?
3. Should I use a resistor between base and emitter (I read that it protects the curcuit)?
4. Is this circuit safe? (BTW I have a BMS on the batteries.)

[image]

Comment: A mosfet doesnt have emitter and base it has source and drain.

Comment: Don't think of a MOSFET as an on/off switch. The value of Vgs in the datasheet is the point at which it just starts to conduct (usually specified at a drain-source current of something like 100 or 250uA). Look at the datasheet for graphs of how it behaves.

Comment: You could use a BJT instead - but not a 2N2222 as it can't handle the current.

Comment: @Finbarr indeed, but the datasheet for this one shows really good numbers if I'm reading it right. although the relevant graph doesn't go lower than 20 amperes :)

Comment: Using a solid state relay would be the safest option to protect your Piko. The input side (Piko) is optically isolated from the output side (heater), and the breakdown voltage between the input and output is hundreds of volts or more. A solid state relay requires a resistor in series with the input side to limit the current draw to the Piko.

Comment: @C.Dunn - Hi, That looks like an answer (even if it is a different solution that the one proposed by the OP). Please do not use comments for answers - see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Instead, write an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @C.Dunn - i think this is the closest that i can implement right now. thank you)

Answer (score -5):

You have several misconceptions:

> Should i use a mosfet or a did smth wrong and i can choose smth like 2n2222?

What you shows us in the circuit diagram is a MOSFET

> Should i use a resistor between 3v3 pin and mosfet base (irlb3034pbf is opened by 1…2.5V if i am correct)

It doesnt make a difference if you put a resistor between the **gate** of the MOSFET because the gate is galvanically isolated from the source and drain.

> Should i use a resistor between base and emitter (i read that it protects the curcuit)?

You are talking about BJTs but you have a MOSFET and it is impossible to put anything between the source and the gate of a MOSFET.

> Is this curcuit safe? (btw i have a bms on batteries)

The MOSFET will most likely be in saturation so current is limited anyway.But the resistor 4Ω is so low that all the power provided by the battery is dissipated on the MOSFET so it will get hot and **may be damaged** permanently.

Since it is in saturation drain current is increasing for increasing voltages Vgs(coming out of your microcontroller) which dont push the MOSFET in active mode so unless your microcontoller can provide 10-11V at its output pins(which I highly doubt) the MOSFET will remain in saturation and making bigger or lower the voltage of the gate will slightly change the current .

Comment: "The MOSFET will most likely be in saturation" Incorrect. The MOSFET will be in its triode region of operation with a small \$V_{DS}\$. Perhaps you were thinking of a BJT instead.

Comment: "But the resistor 4Ω is so low that all the power provided by the battery is dissipated on the MOSFET". Incorrect. The maximum current through the resistor is 3A and the MOSFET can easily handle that. Looking at the datasheet there should be less than 0.1V across the MOSFET with Vgs of 3V hence less than 0.3W dissipated.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Saturation is when Vgs-Vth<Vds and the mosfet acts like a passive current source.You are confusing it with the active region when the mosfet acts like a voltage controlled resistor , controlled by Vgs

Comment: @Finbarr no if the current of the circuit is controlled by a passive current source(in our case the MOSFET in saturation region) in the order of mA and the resistor is 4Ω then the voltage of the resistors will be approximately equal to 0.

Comment: Errrrr...... then what is the current through the MOSFET?

Comment: @MissMulan "making bigger or lower the voltage of the gate doesnt matter." - this is not true. In saturation, you have a VCCS (following square-law), and Vgs absolutely matters. In saturation, all you've done is build a poorly-controlled common-source amplifier which is prone to overheating.

Comment: @nanofarad ok your correct ill edit.

Comment: @Finbarr the current inside the MOSFET when the MOSFET is in saturations depends only on Vgs and Vth as nanofarad correctly pointed out.

Comment: But what will it actually be? Give us a number based on a Vgs of 3V.

Comment: Also please show that the transistor will be in saturation when Vgs=3V and Id<3A.

Comment: The reason the word "saturation" is confusing is that it's the opposite of a BJT. A BJT is saturated when the voltage across the switching terminals can't go any lower - it's fully on. A MOSFET is saturated when the current through the switching terminals can't go any higher - it's *not* fully on.

Comment: I don't agree with your edit, unfortunately. It's *more* accurate than it was before, but "slightly" is a very poor description of square-law behavior and I would consider it misleading.

Comment: You are still incorrectly saying that the MOSFET is in saturation, and I'm still struggling to see how the MOSFET is going to get damaged permanently by heat when the voltage across the resistor is zero.